# Проблемы с анимацией по клику

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Нужно сделать, чтобы по клику на `::before` срабатывала анимация `scale` и `::before` увеличивался в размере, но по клику по `#А3` ничего не происходило, только по `::before`:

```css
#A3 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}

#A3:before {
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="A3"></div>
```

Comment: Насколько мне известно, из JQuery нельзя обращаться к псевдоэлементам.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не можете поймать событие от псевдо-элемента. Единственный способ — проверить вручную координаты клика:

```js
$('#A3').click(function(e) {
  if (e.pageX > 50 && e.pageX < 100 && e.pageY > 50 && e.pageY < 100)
    $('#A3').toggleClass('active')
});
```

```css
#A3 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}
#A3:before {
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
#A3.active:before {
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="A3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Это невозможно. Попробуйте изменить разметку, например:

```
#A3{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background-color:green;
    position:relative;
}
#A3 .pseudo-before{
    content:"";
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
    background-color:black; 
}


var a3bef = document.querySelector('#A3 .pseudo-before');
a3bef.addEventListener('click', scaleUp);

function scaleUp() {
    this.style.transform = 'scale(1.5)';
    event.stopPropagation();
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>google</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/animate.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="A3"><div class="pseudo-before"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0tcu2ptu/

а тут пример, где оно и увеличивается и уменьшается
https://jsfiddle.net/0fxyw7xg/1/